# What's the meaning for "-z" ld command line option

Tags: ld, binutils

The [ld doc](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html) shows that some of the options are prefixed with `-z`:

```
-z keyword
  The recognized keywords are:

  ‘call-nop=prefix-addr’
  ‘call-nop=suffix-nop’
  ‘call-nop=prefix-byte’
  ‘call-nop=suffix-byte’
```

But why these options are so special that need to prefixed `-z`? Are there special meanings for `-z`?
The closest explanation is that those options are ELF specific. I found this in the [Aarch64 commit](https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb/commit/8bf6d176b0a442a8091d338d4af971591d19922c):

> This patch moves the current AArch64 ld options of --force-bti
> and --pac-plt to -z force-bti and -z pac-plt since these are
> ELF specific options.

But I wonder if there any "formal" documentation about it?